# Find $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan x+\tan 2 x+\ldots+\tan n x}{\operatorname{arctg} x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Estimate limit: $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan x+\tan 2 x+\ldots+\tan n x}{\arctan x}.$$

I understand correctly that the tangent and arctangent of an infinitesimal argument are equivalent to it, so instead of $\arctan x $, I can write $\tan x$?

Comment: To simplify, solve for the limit of $$\frac{\tan kx}{\arctan x}=\dfrac{\frac{\tan kx}x}{\frac{\arctan x}x}$$

Comment: You can certainly use: $$\frac{\arctan x}{\tan x}\to1,$$ if you have that result. This lets you replace $\arctan$ here with $\tan.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, that's convenient. Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is it possible if x->0 to replace sin(x^2) with x?

Comment: No, $\sin[x^2)/x\to 0.$ I dislike the word “replace” here, because you can’t **always** replace $\arctan x$ with $\tan x$ in a limit. For example the limit $$\frac{\arctan x-x}{x^3}$$ won’t allow such substitution. But $\frac{\tan x}{\arctan x}\to 1$ means that if the numerator or denomination of a limit is exactly $\arctan x,$ we can do such a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the asymptotic relations:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(\alpha\cdot x)}{\alpha \cdot x}=1$$
And:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}=1$$

So, the numerator becomes:
$$\tan(x)+\tan(2x)+\dots+\tan(nx)\sim x+2x+\dots+nx\,\,\, x\to 0$$

Thus the limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x+\tan(2x)+\ldots+\tan(nx)}{\arctan(x) }=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x\cdot \frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}}{x}=\frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Is it possible if x->0 to replace sin(x^2) with x?

Comment: @Matteo $\sin(x^2)/x\to 0,$ not $\infty.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ops, sorry. My mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @CatMario: absoltely not. Namely: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x)}=1$$ So: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}=0$$